# Static DNS + DHCP-ed IP in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, dns, dhcp

I change wifi networks a couple times a day. Obviously they have different DHCP settings, and I always use dynamic ip resolving.

However, I want to have the same (say, OpenDNS') static nameservers in all networks.

For reference, in Linux, I'd use the `supersede domain-name-servers` option in `dhclient.conf` to set up the preferred DNS addresses.

Is this possible to do in Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you configure your IP just set it to use the OpenDNS server and leave it set to DHCP, that should work out.

[image]

Comment: This may, however, result in loss of access of some internal network resources if your domain controller is a DNS server and the service doesn't support netbios! (another public DNS is 8.8.8.8 which is google!)

Comment: That is a good point, and it would cause issues if the network you are in doesn't allow DNS out.

Comment: Shoot, I thought the "Automatic IP" option disables the "Static DNS" option. Thanks for pointing this out.